# C# Custom TrackBar Buffer Area

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, trackbar

I'm making a User Control to act as a TrackBar. I have a `ToolboxCustomTrackbar1` which has a `Min` and `Max` as well as a `SelectedMin` which can be changed by the user dragging around a `MinPanel` in the area.

The `MinPanel` is drawn based on `SelectedMin`, which is changed with the following code:

```
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);

        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            UpdateSelectedMinFromMouse(e.X);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateSelectedMinFromMouse(float x)
    {
        var percentage = x * 100 / Width;
        var range = Max - Min;
        var rawValue = percentage * range / 100;
        var value = rawValue + Min;

        SelectedMin = (int)Math.Round(value);
    }
```

`MinPanel` is then drawn with the following code:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);

        minPanel.Location = new Point((int)GetPosition(ref selectedMin), 0);
        minPanel.Size = new Size(PanelWidth, Height/2);
        minPanel.BackColor = Color.Red;

        trackbarArea = new Rectangle(Buffer, 0, Width - Buffer * 2, Height);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightBlue, trackbarArea);

    }

    private float GetPosition(ref int input)
    {
        var range = Max - Min;
        var value = input - Min;
        var percentage = (float)value * 100 / range;
        var position = percentage * Width / 100;

        Console.WriteLine(position);

        return position - (float)minPanel.Width / 2;
    }
```

---

This all works fine and draws the `MinPanel` wherever I click and drag on the control. However, I want to allow for a buffer area on the left and right of the control so as to draw the entire `MinPanel` even when it's at the left and right edges of the control.

I'm currently trying to do this with:

`Rectangle trackbarArea = new Rectangle(Buffer, 0, Width - Buffer * 2, Height);`

And this creates the area which I actually want to be considered the range for my `TrackBar`.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to have my control treat the Left edge of `trackbarArea` as the Min spot and the Right edge as the Max spot.

**How can I allow my TrackBar to work with a Buffer on either side of it?**

Comment: You could try to set the ClientRectangle to your trackbarArea, not sure tho. Otherwise you could try recreating the Trackbar-Control from scratch,
 like I did here :https://github.com/glm9637/MaterialWinforms/blob/master/MaterialWinforms/Controls/MaterialSlider.cs

Comment: Haha I'm not familiar or experienced enough to do that, thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

I created a `ShiftOffset` variable which I essentially use to offset both the `Min` and the `Max`:

```
private int ShiftOffset
{
    get { return shiftOffset; }
    set { shiftOffset = value; }
}
private int Min
{
    get { return min - ShiftOffset; }
    set { min = value; }
}
private int Max
{
    get { return max + ShiftOffset; }
    set { max = value; }
}
```

Then, everytime I set a value, I `ValidateValue()` using:

```
private void ValidateValue(ref int value)
{
    if (value < Min + ShiftOffset) value = Min + ShiftOffset;
    if (value > Max - ShiftOffset) value = Max - ShiftOffset;
}
```

In my `User Control` initialization, I set `ShiftOffset = NormalizeSize(PanelWidth * 100);` but I have yet to figure out what the appropriate value for `ShiftOffset` is in order to leave room to draw the last half of the `Panels`.

I'm trying to do some sort of `PanelWidth * (Max - Min) / Width` or some variation, but I can't quite get it.